# Copy all files from several folders to one folder in same directory

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to copy all files from several folders to one folder in the same directory. 
I have create a Batch file, which contains

```
MD PATCHCON
for /R %cd% %%f in (*.*) do copy %%f %cd%\PATCHCON
pause
```

If I put this on the desktop, it runs successfully; if I run the same code in the dir it's not working.

This code also copies my batch file in consolidate folder`<patchcon>` so I also want to add a code line that does not copy my batch file.

Comment: I edited it to make it say what I think you mean; if you feel I changed too much, feel free to roll back.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of issues which you may not have realised.

Firstly it will fail in folders or files that have a `space` or `&` in the name or path.

The other issue is that it will try to copy some files in the `PATCHCON` folder twice.

This should solve those problems and remove the batch file itself from the folder.

```
@echo off
MD "..\PATCHCON"
for /R "%cd%" %%f in (*) do copy "%%f" "..\PATCHCON" >nul
del "..\PATCHCON" "%~nx0"
move "..\PATCHCON" . >nul
echo done.
pause
```